# Search the list of values in another array of objects and change the one key in array of objects using single for loop

Tags: javascript

I want to change the 'selected' key value in emps, if the empIds are available. I tried the below logic using two for loops. I was trying the logic using single for loop, but it didn't work. Any one has some idea on single for loop logic. Please give some sample logic on it.

**Below are sample formats of array values and array of objects**

```
// values in list are dynamic
empIds = [1,3];

// object values in array are dynamic
emps = [{
id: 1,
name:'test1',
selected: false
},
{
id: 2,
name:'test2',
selected: false
},
{
id: 3,
name:'test3',
selected: false
}];

// logic 
for (var i = 0; i< empIds.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j< emps.length; j++) {
    if (empIds[i] === emps[j].id) {
       emps[j].selected = true;
     } else {
         emps[j].selected = false;
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple forEach and includes

```js
const empIds = [1, 3];

// object values in array are dynamic
const emps = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test1',
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test2',
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'test3',
    selected: false
  }
];

emps.forEach(e => e.selected = empIds.includes(e.id));

console.log(emps);
```

Comment: Thanks you for help. I have observed one issue in IE11, includes() is not supporting in IE11. So instead of includes, replaced it with indexOf(). emps.forEach(e => e.selected = (empIds.indexOf(e.id) !== -1));

Comment: You’re welcome. Yes that works the same. Feel free to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

For a solution with low complexity, I'd suggest creating a `Map` of the `emps` in advance, indexed by `id`, and then you can iterate over the `empIds` and access the appropriate object directly, `O(N)`:

```js
const empIds = [1, 3];
const emps = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test1',
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test2',
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'test3',
    selected: false
  }
];
const empsById = emps.reduce((map, emp) => map.set(emp.id, emp), new Map());
empIds.forEach((id) => empsById.get(id).selected = true);
console.log(emps);
```

You could also do a nested `.find` in a `forEach` to find the appropriate object in the array, but that's basically the equivalent of two `for` loops and is `O(N^2)`.